# How to use gradle properties in build.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, java-home

When I run this task:

```
task tmpTask << {
    project.properties.each {println "   $it"}
}
```

I see:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

But how to use this variable? I've tried both:

```
task tmpTask << {
    println org.gradle.java.home
    println project.properties.org.gradle.java.home
}
```

But none of this works. First print gives error:

```
Could not find property 'org' on task ':tmpTask'.
```

while second fails with:

```
Cannot get property 'gradle' on null object
```

Comment: Your method gives me `Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_3vobal41blt05kb5pvio1jbbm$_run_closure12@33fabf91] on task ':tmpTask' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[`project.properties`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:properties) is a `Map<String, ?>`

So you can use

```
project.properties['org.gradle.java.home']
```

You can also use the [property()](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:property%28java.lang.String%29) method (but that looks in additional locations):

```
project.property('org.gradle.java.home')
```

Answer (score 31):

For anyone else's benefit. If the property you define is not dot separated, then you can simply refer to it directly.

In your `gradle.properties`:

```
myProperty=This is my direct property
my.property=This is my dotted property with\t\t tabs \n and newlines
```

In your `build.gradle`:

```
// this works
println myProperty
println project.property('my.property')

// this will not
println my.property
```

Comment: So like, this is exactly what I wanted to have working, and yet it doesn't for me with a gradle.properties with one line `VER_SPOTLESS=3.13.0` I can't print it in a task.
`Could not get unknown property 'VER_SPOTLESS' for task ':hello' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.`

Comment: It also doesn't work for me. Perhaps its because I'm using a `build.gradle.kts` file

Answer (score 11):

#### From `gradle.properties`

Add prop to the file `gradle.properties`

```
hi1=hi
```

#### From CommandLine

Add `-Pxxx` end of command line.

```
./gradlew -q readPropertiesTask -Phi2=tete
```

Several properties：

```
./gradlew -q readPropertiesTask -Phi2=tete -Phi3=rr
```

#### How to read?

```
val propFromFile = project.properties["hi1"]
println("propFromFile = $propFromFile")
```