# Gradle - Fails to show: org.gradle.java.home

Tags: java, properties, gradle

I thought this would be a very simple thing. So far however I'm unable to *access* the String for my gradle job's Java.Home, the official name:

- For example, see: [org.gradle.java.home](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/gradle/gradle-properties-build-configuration-example/)

Apparently I can set this value with gradle.properties settings file. I've done that and the gradle output confirms this.

For all that, none of these print statements work...

- print "org.gradle.java.home = $org.gradle.java.home"
- print "org.gradle.java.home = "+ project.properties['org.gradle.java.home']
- print  "org.gradle.java.home = $gradle.java.home"
- print "${project.property('org.gradle.java.home')}"

Looking at back at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170539/how-to-use-gradle-properties-in-build-gradle/30171210) question, I would have thought one of the options tried would yield a result.

How can I access system level properties?

Answer (score 2):

Only two options may work:

- `print "org.gradle.java.home = "+ project.properties['org.gradle.java.home']`
- `print "${project.property('org.gradle.java.home')}"`

and the second will fail since there's no checking if such property exists. Gradle throws an exception on access to non-existing property.

The last two will not work because there's no property *org* and *gradle* objects has no *java* property - more explanation can be found [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) - you need to understand how string interpolation works with groovy.

And finally, these properties are used to **pass** arguments to gradle. So the following will work:

```
print "org.gradle.java.home = "+
```

project.properties['org.gradle.java.home']

run with:

```
gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home=random_dir
```

Comment: The phrase: **print "org.gradle.java.home = "+ project.properties['org.gradle.java.home']** gives: "org.gradle.java.home = null:help"; while the other variations don't work or give _"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."_ results.

Comment: I'm concluding that while one may set the _java.home_ property it is not readable.  There are some notes about it only being supported by the Gradle daemon.  Said daemon reports that a new JVM is fork-ed and I'm considering that the  _java.home_ property is not transitive.  Definitely inconsistent in my view.  Perhaps a release later than 2.4 will resolve things.

Comment: Yes, because only with this phrase you refer to this property correctly. You need to *pass* the property to read it. As I wrote in *run with:*.

Comment: I beg pardon there, I was too abbreviated with my comment.  When passing a **valid JDK** path, the answer is _"**null:help**"_.  Stackoverflow comment boxes are not suitable for long descriptions.  
  
**gradle** -Dorg.gradle.java.home=%JDK_8%  
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked.  
Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.  

org.gradle.java.home = null:help   
  
Ergo my theory that, the property is not passed into the fork-ed environment.

Comment: Yes it may be not passed.

Comment: While the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables) suggests that `org.gradle.java.home` is _always_ set, I found it isn't, even with `--no-daemon` (in `afterEvaluate` code provided by a plugin). Using `System.getProperty("java.home")` did the job in the plugin code; not sure if it's accessible in the build script itself.

Answer (score 0):

With some trial-and-much-error, I have found that one may print the *java.home* property on Windows with Gradle 2.4; when ...

- Use your **gradle.properties** file, e.g.

For example

```
  compile.options.fork    = true  
  org.gradle.daemon       = true  
  org.gradle.java.home    = b:/lang/java/jdk/v1.8u45
```

The same settings in GRADLE_OPTS had no effect.  The print command used, is:

```
 print "org.gradle.java.home = "+ "${project.property('org.gradle.java.home')}"
```

I believe the *compile.options.fork* is also required.  It had no effect before when I was using GRADLE_OPTS.  Although the Gradle message to use fork is quite clear on the matter.

*see also*:
- https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html